# Using grep in Python to search for exact words only

Tags: python-3.x, grep

I am trying to use grep in Python to search for words in a text file. I tried something like this -

```
subprocess.call(['/bin/grep', str(word), "textFile.txt"])
```

This line is printing all output on console. Also, it is returning true even if the word is not matching exactly. For example, it returns a word even for this match -
xxxwordsxxx

```
def find_words(in_file, out_file):
    for word in in_file:
        word = word.rstrip()
        subprocess.call(["grep", "-w",  word, "textFile.txt"])
```

**edit**
My in_file and textFile.txt are the same.

How do I implement a search for the exact word? If this is not a correct way, is there any other way I could do this search? (It is a huge text file and I have to find duplicates of all the words in the file)

Comment: `subprocess.clas` - is incorrect

Comment: `call` should be used, `clas` is a typo. As for the whole word, can you try replacing `word` with `r"\b{}\b".format(word)`? Or `r"\<{}\>".format(word)`? Or even maybe `r"[[:<:]]{}[[:>:]]".format(word)`? You may remove `"-w"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried replacing `word` with `r"\b{}\b".format(word)` and I am still facing the same isue

Answer (score 0):

Try using parameter -w:

```
import subprocess

word = input("select word to filter: ")

subprocess.call(['/bin/grep', "-w", word, "textFile.txt"]) #str is not needed
```

Comment: It is still returning sub-words

Comment: @MMG I ran exactly this script, in linux, see my updated answer, and it doesn't gives me the subwords with parameter "-w", and it does without it. I ran it in console terminal like "python scrp.py"

Comment: So if enter a particular string, it returns the correct match. But I am looping through the input file, and pass a string variable, it messes up. The type of the variable is - <class 'str'>

Comment: @MMG could you add to the question how exactly are you doing all the process? a little sample of the input and the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.split()` method to iterate over individual words from the line. For example:

```
string = "My Name Is Josh"
substring = "Name"
for word in string.split():
    if substring == word:
        print("Match Found")
```

Comment: can you edit the code to make it valid python, and provide some explanation for why this works? You can use comments in the code to indicate what's different about your approach, rather than asterisks